# The answer is a specific PSE question

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cipher

> uxymu uxymu gry'c drobo xykr xykr gry xykr zvkmo s mkx czoxn dyxsqrd[image]

The answer is a question you can find only on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [The Mystery of NOC-10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10633/the-mystery-of-noc-10/10720#10720)

uxymu uxymu gry'c drobo xykr xykr gry xykr zvkmo s mkx czoxn dyxsqrd

> -This can be decrypted using ROT-16 for "knock knock who's there noah noah who noah place i can spend tonight"
>  -The use of rot **16** conveniently hints at the 16 equal sounds in video 3.
>  -"knock" hints at "NOC" (sounds smilar)
>  -Note that (credit the geniuses codewarrior and stiv) the rot-16 decryption means it was encrypted with rot-10, hinting at NOC-10
>  -The map in this puzzle is roughly centered and zoomed in on the geographic location that is the solution to the NOC puzzle (in the Mariana trench). (this was the most direct clue)
>  -'Noah' hints at the maritime theme of the NOC puzzle

None of these alone are conclusive enough to link this to a specific puzzle, but put together the solution was clear.

Comment: Encrypting with Rot13 is the same as decrypting with Rot13, but this is not true for other numbers.

Comment: @codewarrior0 Indeed. It can be *decrypted* via this method because it's *encrypted* using rot13(Ebg-gra - naq vg'f gung ahzore gung'f fvtavsvpnag gb gur 'ABP-gra' bs gur dhrfgvba gvgyr. Gur fvkgrra vf cher pbvapvqrapr, V srry, naq abg gur fvtavsvpnag nfcrpg urer...)

Comment: ah. i get confused with encryption and decryption, so that is why it happpened :)